# Do I need a sort key in DynamoDB if my partition key is unique?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What's the benefit of having a sort key if I already have a primary key [partition key] that is unique?

Comment: This is obviously dependent on the data hierarchy in a given application and your desired query patterns. If you needed to, for example, retrieve the newest blog posts from a given user then a simple partition key would not work at all. You'd likely need something like pk=userid, sk=timestamp+uuid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort keys have two benefits:

1. They gather related information together in one place where it can be queried efficiently. Careful design of the sort key lets you retrieve commonly needed groups of related items using range queries with operators such as begins_with, between, >, <, and so on.
2. Composite sort keys let you define hierarchical (one-to-many) relationships in your data that you can query at any level of the hierarchy.

That being said it's completely fine to have a table with partition key only but u will probably need a sort key at some point.

Comment: To add to this answer: Without a Sort Key and a good understanding of your Access Patterns, you will be forced to either do a Scan (very intensive in terms of Read Capacity Units and time) or make use of multiple Indexes (which can lag behind the actual data updates). if you ever need to look up your data by some method other than your unique primary key.   #1 in the answer above is a perfect reason to have a carefully designed by Access Pattern dynamo table.